# Looking for an organized list of ActiveX object IDs for embedding

Tags: activex, embed, dhtml, activexobject, realbasic

I'm currently developing an application using Real Studio.  Vaguely similar to Visual Basic, it provides the means by which to embed ActiveX objects inside an OLE Container.  That said, I need an alphabetical list of available ActiveX components similar to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee797043(v=cs.20).aspx) that provides me with Program IDs such as:

- "InternetExplorer.Application"
- "Excel.Application"
- "ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"

One could assume that everything is simply named literally (after the application itself), but I'm not after an application in this instance.  Specifically I am in need of a DHTML control for an editable HTML viewer.  Generally I'd like to be able to reference this information for future control embedding.

I may be asking the wrong question, but if there are any mind readers out there,any assistance would be much appreciated.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a search engine for IE extensions that include HTML:

- [CLSID list of HTML items](http://www.systemlookup.com/lists.php?list=1&type=name&search=html&s=)